# how to use string value in Order By clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a table in the database that consists of 10 columns, the header name for each column is

> 'Col' + column number

look like this

```
id|Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4|Col5|Col6
```

i have a SQL statment that run through a Stored procedure this stored take column number as a parameter

```
@ColumnNumber nvarchar(10)
```

all i want to do is ordering the result by column number that will be passed in the parameter , something like this

```
Select   * from [Table] order by  ('Col' + @ColumnNumber)
```

but it doesn't work with me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create dynamic SQL to make it work like

```
DECLARE @ColumnNumber nvarchar(10)
DECLARE @strSQL nvarchar(max)
SET @ColumnNumber = '1'

SET @strSQL = 'Select * from [Table] order by Col' + @ColumnNumber
EXEC(@strSQL)
```

**UPDATE :** 
If you have @List variable of XML type which have multiple ids then you can get in comma separated format like below

```
DECLARE @RecordIds nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @List XML = '<Records><id>1</id></Records><Records><id>2</id></Records>'

SELECT  @RecordIds = STUFF((SELECT ',' + RecordId.value('.','varchar(5)') 
                            FROM @List.nodes('Records/id') AS Test(RecordId)
                FOR XML PATH (''))
                , 1, 1, '')
```

Then you can use that comma separated string in your query like

```
SET @strSQL = 'Select * from [Table] where Id in ( ' + @RecordIds + ' ) order by Col' + @ColumnNumber
```

Comment: It is very important to note that @ColumnNumber was casted to a length of 5.  This prevents possible SQL Injection since I do not know any commands that are 2 characters in length  - '1--'

Comment: @Upendra thank u it looks good idea, but i want to know how can i put this sql code in the variable @strSQL===>
Select   * from Table
 where  Id  in  (
         SELECT  RecordId.value('.','int')
     FROM @List.nodes('Records/id') AS Table(RecordId))

Comment: what is @List ? it's xml variable ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @ColumnNumber INT
SET @ColumnNumber = 1

SELECT *
FROM [Table]
ORDER BY 
    CASE @ColumnNumber
        WHEN 1 THEN Col1
        WHEN 2 THEN Col2
        WHEN 3 THEN Col3
    END
```

Answer (score 3):

Without using dynamic SQL you can do it using CASE statement:

```
SELECT * FROM [Table]
        ORDER BY CASE @ColumnNumber
           WHEN 1 THEN Col1
           WHEN 2 THEN Col2
           WHEN 3 THEN Col3
           .....
           WHEN 10 THEN Col10
         END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
DECLARE @ColumnNumber NVARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(100)

SET @ColumnNumber = '1'
SET @sql = 'Select * from TEST_EXISTS order by COL' + @ColumnNumber + ' DESC'

PRINT @sql

EXEC (@SQL)
```